# How do we find maxima and minima for a discrete-time function

Tags: calculus

To find maxima and minima of a continuous-time signal we can use differentiation. I want to know how do we find maxima and minima of a discrete-time signal?

Comment: The answer probably depends on the signal. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can still do the differentiation but numerically. Then the argument which indicates ablolutely minimum value is what you are after.

Other way would be to sort you data in descending order, if it is finite, and take the first element.